# How to fix Logits and Labels must have the same shape?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm building a neural network, and while calling

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.1), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((5, 560, 2) vs (5, 1, 1))

A bit of background, the data I'm using is pixel data from images. Data_x is a 3d NumPy array where the first dimension is a different image and the 2nd and 3rd is an array of pixels for that image it looks like this:

```
(32086, 560, 560)
```

My Data_Y is for my labels and the NN should be making a binary decision so the labels are either 1 or 0.
It looks like this:

```
(32086, 1, 1)
```

I access the data as follows:

```
f = gzip.GzipFile('Data_x.npy.gz', "r")
datax = np.load(f)[:5, :, :]
f.close()
f = gzip.GzipFile('Data_y.npy.gz', "r")
datay = np.load(f)[:5, :, :]
f.close()
```

The error states that they should be the same shape but it doesn't make sense that each pixel should have a label only for each separate image.

This is my model architecture:

```
model = Sequential(
[
    Dense(750, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(750, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
]
```

)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try GlobalMaxPooling1D with keepdims=True before the last Dense/Dropout and again change the units from 2 to 1 of the last Dense

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Is that the layer's only input because I then got this error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer global_max_pooling1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 5, 560, 750)

Comment: you declared to have inputs of shape (32086, 560, 560) and this is not 4D... maybe you miss to report something... however if your data is 4D use GlobalMaxPooling2D

Comment: @MarcoCerliani When I use 1D it says its input is 4D but when I switch to 2D it says its input is 3D. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use your densely connected network on 2D image Data directly? That way your network is applied to each column instead of all pixels at once. It's more common to use a `flatten` layer first to unfold the 2D Matrix into a 1D Vector and apply the network to that vector. With that many pixels however that would be a very large Model.